# how to transfer data in DataGridView to table in Report RDLC

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, report

i need help in this issue:
im developing a vb.net app which connected to access 2007 db and there a form that user can enter some data then print it
so.. sometimes the user need to print a table with that data!
how can i transfer the data inserted in DGV to report to be printed with other string value (this seems to be like a Letter)
every time the user has different rows and columns count!
and every time the user has different column width!
i used this code to connect to db:

```
Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" & dbpath & "
Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr)
Dim ds As New DataTable
Dim SQLstr As String = "select id,ldate,lnum,ltype from tblletter"
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr, Conn)
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLstr, Conn)
da.Fill(ds)
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
```

Comment: Create an `RDLC` report using the query `select id,ldate,lnum,ltype from tblletter`, then set the data source of your report to the table that you use as `DataGridView` data source.

Comment: i used this code ( ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources = ds ) but i don't think this right!!!